# How can I see the diff of two commits with respect to another one?

Tags: git, gitkraken

Example: There is a commit A and two branches from A: B and C. In the end, B and C are merged into D.
I want to see if the difference between D and B is exactly the changes made in C.

```
      -- B --
    /        \
A ------ C --- D
```

The problem I have is that the merge D has a bug related to the changes made in B which were definitely not there when B was developed.

Comment: Why don't you try merging them separately and them comparing with D to see what was added/missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to see if the difference between D and B is exactly the changes made in C

Sounds like you want [git range-diff](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-range-diff)

```
git range-diff B..D A..C
```